# Textarea in iOS cordova application accepts input only once

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, textarea

Specifically, the textarea value can be changed by input from the soft keyboard exactly once after the application is installed. This is a single-page app where I am using Handlebars for templating. Here is the template:

```
<script id="comment-form-tpl" type="text/template">
        <header class="bar bar-nav">
          <a href="#" class="btn btn-link btn-nav pull-left">
            Cancel
          </a>
          <h1 class="title">Add Comment</h1>
        </header>
        <div class="bar bar-standard bar-footer">
          <button type="button" id="save-comment" class="btn btn-block">Save</button>
        </div>
        <div class="content">
          <form class="input-group">
            <textarea id="comment-text" placeholder="Comment" rows="10" autofocus>{{{comment}}}</textarea> 
          </form>
        </div>
    </script>
```

I am getting the input from the textarea using javascript attached to the Save button:

```
var CommentAddView = function() {
var Comment = new Object();

this.initialize = function() {
    this.$el = $('<div/>');
    this.$el.on('click', '#save-comment', this.saveComment);
    if (window.localStorage.getItem("comment")) {
        var text = window.localStorage.getItem("comment");
        text = text.replace(/<br>/g, "\n");
        this.setComment(text);
    }
    this.render();
};

this.render = function() {
    this.$el.html(this.template(Comment));
    return this;
};

this.setComment = function(text) {
    Comment.comment = text;
}; 

this.saveComment = function() {
    var text = $("#comment-text").val();
    text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
    window.localStorage.setItem("comment", text);
    router.load('');
};

this.initialize();
```

};

This all works perfectly exactly once -- the textarea shows up with the soft keyboard, I can type something in, and it is saved to local storage.
However, editing doesn't work: as you can see, if there's a "comment" value in local storage, it's put in the the textarea. This works, but the value can't be changed. I can enter new text using the soft keyboard and it will show in the textarea, but when I touch "Save", I can verify by logging to the console that `$("#comment-text").val()` has not changed. Similarly with trying to delete: deleting removes the value of "comment" from local storage. If I try to enter a new comment, the textarea appears blank, and I can type in a new comment, but when I try to save, the value of `$("#comment-text").val()` is the first, supposedly deleted comment! If I try to fix this by putting the line
    `$("#comment-text").val("");`
then `$("#comment-text").val()` is indeed empty ... but it still can't be changed by keyboard input. Everything works properly if I just open the app in Safari on my desktop; so this is specifically an iOS (or possibly just iPhone) problem. I'm testing on iOS 8.1.3. I've Googled away, and tried everything that seemed like it might be remotely related, but I'm out of ideas. Anybody know what's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Got it, finally! I added the line: `$("#comment-text").remove();` to the `saveComment` function. So:

```
this.saveComment = function() {
    var text = $("#comment-text").val();
    $("#comment-text").remove();
    text = text.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
    window.localStorage.setItem("comment", text);
    router.load('');
};
```

I am creating a new `CommentAddView` object each time the comment form is displayed, but I finally realized that jQuery is acting as though the previous one is still there. Explicitly removing it solves this problem.